# How to set auto image slider with the help of sliderlayout in android studio

Tags: android, android-layout, androidimageslider

How to create auto image slider with the help of com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout in android studio

I was trying to create a autoimage slider with the help of com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout
under the fragment but when i run the the app its show some errors

**Errors**

```
  Process: com.example.mycollege, PID: 23523
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mycollege/com.example.mycollege.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2887)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2965)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1669)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:192)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6702)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:549)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:826)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
```

**fragement_home.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.home.homeFragment">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
      <com.smarteist.autoimageslider.SliderLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="250dp"
          android:id="@+id/slider_image"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:text="HOME"/>
</ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>
```

**homefragement.java**

```
public class homeFragment extends Fragment {
    private SliderLayout sliderLayout;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
        sliderLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.slider_image);
        sliderLayout.setIndicatorAnimation(IndicatorAnimations.FILL);
        sliderLayout.setSliderTransformAnimation(SliderAnimations.SIMPLETRANSFORMATION);
        sliderLayout.setScrollTimeInSec(1);
        setsliderview();
        return view;
    }
    private void setsliderview() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            DefaultSliderView defaultSliderView = new DefaultSliderView(getContext());
            switch (i) {
                case 0:
                    defaultSliderView.setImageUrl("Imageurl");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    defaultSliderView.setImageUrl("Imageurl");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    defaultSliderView.setImageUrl("Imageurl");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    defaultSliderView.setImageUrl("Imageurl");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    defaultSliderView.setImageUrl("Imageurl");
                    break;
            }
            defaultSliderView.setImageScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            sliderLayout.addSliderView(defaultSliderView);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use view pager 2

Comment: is  my method is wrong ?